# Sending an SMS does not proceed

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, sharedpreferences

In my app I am sending text message where number intent from first activity but SMS sending failed

The Phone Number is intent and I am using shared-preferences class to intent

```
package com.jsm.irs;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;     
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import com.jsm.irs.SharedPreference;   
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;


public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

// UI References
private TextView textTxt;

private String text;

private SharedPreference sharedPreference;

Activity context = this;

Button btnCall;
EditText txtDated;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

    btnCall = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCal);
    txtDated = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    findViewsById();

    //Retrieve a value from SharedPreference
    text = sharedPreference.getValue(context);
    textTxt.setText(text);




}







private void findViewsById() {
    textTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
           sendSMSMessage();

        }
    });
 }






protected void sendSMSMessage() {
    Log.i("Send SMS", "");
    String phoneNo = textTxt.getText().toString();
    String message = txtDated.getText().toString();

    try {
       SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
       smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: any errors in this code or in a log file? Does the exception get printed? Am I correct that the only issue is in `sendSMSMessage()`? If so why did you paste all that other code? You might want to visit [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At least add the output of `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: SMS faild, please try again.
Toast show only.no error in the code.

Comment: Yes issue in SMSmanager.

Comment: The reason for paste all the code because number has been intent for other activity.